# Python JSON AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python.
Python 3.7.6

```
import json
fil='numbers.json'
num=[]
with open(fil,'r') as file :
    for obj in file :
        num.append(json.load(obj))
print(num)
```

This is the JSON  file :

`"45""56""78""75"`

This is the error I am getting while running the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/untitled/tetu.py", line 6, in <module>
    num.append(json.load(obj))
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The example in your post: `"45""56""78""75"` is definitely not a JSON format.

Comment: That is not even close to being a proper JSON file, and also it's unclear how you want the code to work even looking beyond that. JSON is meant to be loaded all at once, not line-by-line. Any given line of a valid JSON file is probably not valid JSON.

Comment: Hey and welcome, please read about hot to use JSON, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp 
Also you can validate your JSON here 
https://jsonlint.com/?code=

Comment: "line-by-line" JSON exists:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON  and e.g. for some kind of a log file is it a reasonable internal format.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly your file content is not json.

Given a valid json file content `/tmp/a.json`:

```
{"a": 123}
```

`json.load()` accepts file object like:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('/tmp/a.json', 'r') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
...     print(data)
... 
{'a': 123}
```

Your error comes from iterating the file object, which reads each line into string

```
>>> with open('/tmp/a.json', 'r') as f:
...     for i in f:
...             print(i.__class__)
... 
<class 'str'>
```

In this case, you will need to use `json.loads()` which accepts a json string

```
>>> with open('/tmp/a.json', 'r') as f:
...     for i in f:
...             print(json.loads(i))
... 
{'a': 123}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the use of json extension for a non-json file, the issue with your code is that `obj` is a string in your code, not a file, so you should use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`. On the other hand, if you know that each line is a number, you may convert the literal integer with `int`.